# Info Needed: What are some of the best PL/SQL Blogs to follow?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am new to `PL/SQL` and I want to understand different aspects of `PL/SQL` so I have couple of questions,

1. What concepts should a developer
   know to call himself as an PL/SQL
   Developer ?
2. What are the best blogs available which `pl/sql` developer should
   follow ?

**Note:** Google Search didn't gave that fruitful results.

Comment: well, there's www.oaktable.net, and orana.info, and then there's my blog... :)

Comment: I am voting to re-open as I am not convinced with the reason for closing this question. If SO still feels that this is an unreasonable question then I am happy to delete it.

Comment: Also vote to reopen. Might do better on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every PL/SQL developer should read [Oracle PL/SQL Programming](http://bit.ly/d2SU9l) by Steven Feuerstein as an excellent introduction to the structure of the language and how it differs from most languages by its database-specific nature.

In addition to a good working knowledge of the Oracle Database, some key concepts to understand in PL/SQL include (but are not limited to):

- The execution environment, being "inside" the database
- The BEGIN/END block structure
- Packages, procedures, functions, triggers, as well as anonymous blocks
- Cursors & Iterative row processing vs Bulk row processing
- Exception handling
- Dynamic SQL & Execute Immediate
- Collections & Records
- Database Transaction Management

For blogs, take a look at Steven Feuerstein's PL/SQL Blog.

http://toadworld.com/Community/ExpertsBlog/tabid/67/BlogID/13/Default.aspx

He's got lots more resources on his site as well. Take a look at the PL/SQL challenge!

http://www.stevenfeuerstein.com

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much too add to what has already been said, other then:

- first learn about the database and about SQL, before you start with PL/SQL
- another site that is indispensable for PL/SQL developers - and that hasn't been mentioned yet - is http://www.oracle-developer.net/: excellent articles per feature and version.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Every PL/SQL developer should participate in PL/SQL Challenge (Steven Feurstein again) site: http://www.plsqlchallenge.com/

It`s a good way to improve your PL/SQL skills or learn this programming language.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** The most important thing to understand about PL/SQL is why you don't want to be a PL/SQL Developer.

To get the most out of your database you need to use declarative programming with sets, also known as SQL.  PL/SQL is procedural programming with rows.  If you only use SQL your code will be simpler and usually about an order of magnitude faster.

Your time is much better spent learning about Oracle and SQL concepts first, and then PL/SQL.  You'll probably be better off as an Oracle Developer who just happens to write some PL/SQL.

**2:** Almost every good Oracle blog is by someone who is a member of the [OakTable](http://www.oaktable.net/members).
But you won't find a lot of PL/SQL there because PL/SQL is not very interesting.  I'm not trying to rant about PL/SQL, I think it's a fine language, but it's massively over-used.  90% of all PL/SQL code should probably be re-written in either SQL or Java/C#/etc.

BUT... before you start looking at blogs or Googling you absolutely need to become familiar with a few books from the Oracle documentation library.

- [Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm)
- [SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm)
- [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/toc.htm)
- [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/toc.htm) (this one is huge and is mostly weird
  stuff nobody uses, but there's also
  some really important stuff in there)

You need to at least be familiar with the structure of those books, especially the SQL and PL/SQL reference, so you can look up things later.  Although they are large and complicated they are also extremely thorough and accurate.  The syntax diagrams alone will save you many hours of Googling.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted. As a PL/SQL developer I agree with every line, except for the idea of rewriting PL/SQL in Java/C#/etc... :)

Comment: I dont like perspective where people try to make everything inside SQL. The maintenance is horrible and usually logic is developed further and further and the result is definitely against every good programming practice.

Comment: @Jeff: and that line is exactly the reason why a downvote had crossed my mind as well. The other lines are pretty sensible so I'll leave it untouched.

Comment: I'd be interested in the arguments for rewriting 90% of pl/sql in Java/C#.  Perhaps @jonearles can add to that statement.

Comment: @Jeff, @Rob, @tbone: That didn't come out right.  I should have said something like "89% should be SQL, and 1% should be Java/C#/C/etc".  I was thinking of those rare cases where you need to do  high performance math, or something that isn't even related to the data, or when some people want to use the latest cool programming language feature that doesn't really work in PL/SQL.  But all of those points can be argued, I probably should have just left it at "SQL".